# Weird (but correct) converse double output

Tags: python

### Issue

So I decided that I needed to get back to basics and do some good old fashioned coding challenges. I know it's much more complex than it really needs to be, but I was board. (For refernce, [here's the link to the challenge readme](https://github.com/rckt-cmdr/dcp-1).)

Anyway, for some reason, both code paths get executed; `evaluate()` & `evaluateSinglePass()` both work as expected and return the expected results when they are supposed to, but I cannot figure out why they both get executed (see the output examples below the code). Even the unit tests give the same output!

What am I missing?

---

### Source Code

```py
import argparse
import sys


def main():         
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="dcp1.py", description="Daily Coding Challenge #1")
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--list", nargs="*", type=str, help="A sequence of at least 2 numbers, separated by <space character>", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--integer", nargs=1, type=int, help="A single integer for comparison", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--optimized", action="store_true", help="Evaluate the sequence with an optimized algorithm")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # converting list sequence to all ints
    listInput = [int(i) for i in args.list]
    kValueInput = int(args.integer[0])  # not sure why, but can only get value this way

    if len(listInput) < 2:
        print("\n\nNot enough numbers in the sequence!\n")
        sys.exit()
    elif args.optimized:
        print("in optimized code branch")
        evaluateSinglePass(listInput, kValueInput)
    else:
        print("in non-optimized code branch")
        evaluate(listInput, kValueInput)


def evaluate(numbers:list, kValue:int):
    numPairFound = False  # assuming false until proven true

    for num1 in numbers:
        for num2 in numbers:
            if num1 + num2 == kValue:
                numPairFound = True
                print(f"\n>> Found one! [{num1} + {num2} = {kValue}]\n\n")

    if not numPairFound:
        print(f"\n>> No combination of numbers add up to {kValue}\n\n")

    return numPairFound


def evaluateSinglePass(numbers:list, kValue:int):
    numPairFound = False  # assuming false until proven true
    
    numbers.sort()
    for num in numbers:
        if kValue - num in numbers:
            numPairFound = True
            print(f"\n>> Found one! [{num} + {kValue - num} = {kValue}]\n\n")
    
    if not numPairFound:
        print(f"\n>> No combination of numbers add up to {kValue}\n\n")

    return numPairFound


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Output

**Running in normal mode:**

```bsh
❯(venv-win)  py src/dcp1.py --list 10 15 3 7 --integer 17
in non-optimized code branch

>> Found one! [10 + 7 = 17]



>> Found one! [7 + 10 = 17]
```

**Running in optimized (single pass) mode:**

```bsh
❯(venv-win)  py src/dcp1.py --list 10 15 3 7 --integer 17 -o
in optimized code branch

>> Found one! [7 + 10 = 17]



>> Found one! [10 + 7 = 17]
```

Comment: the for-loop is not breaking after print.

Comment: which for-loop are you referring to? Or both?

Comment: Turns out it was both of them.

Comment: A more minimal [mre] might have factored out the command-line parsing; no reason to include argparse as part of the question when you could just hardcode a specific function call that triggers the problem, and focus the question only on an individual function itself.

Comment: If the `args` produced by the parsing is right, then you can skip that tag, and focus your question on the post parsing code.

Comment: @Charles, you're right, and indeed I did do that at first. Line I said, I was bored and wanted to make it more interesting.

Comment: @hpaulj, could you expand on that please?

Comment: _nod_. Thing is, we're not really aiming for interesting. The goal of the site is to be a huge FAQ -- lots of tiny, tightly-scoped questions, each with an answer that's as canonical as possible. Once a question gets more complex than it needs to be, it's harder for others to use (or even identify as relevant to their own problem). The way I read hpaulj's comment is effectively echoing that sentiment -- if `argparse` works right, there's no need for the question to include argparse code or have the argparse tag applied.

Comment: AH, ok. I didn't realize you were talking about the post tags. Also didn't fully understand the function of the tags, so thanks. Tag removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks **@muratgu**, for pointing me to the for-loops and the need to break out of them, especially the nested ones in `evaluate()`. Everything works as it should now!

### Modified Code:

```py
def evaluate(numbers:list, kValue:int):
    numPairFound = False  # assuming false until proven true

    for num1 in numbers:
        if not numPairFound:
            for num2 in numbers:
                if num1 + num2 == kValue:
                    numPairFound = True
                    print(f"\n>> Found one! [{num1} + {num2} = {kValue}]\n\n")
                    break
        else:
            break

    if not numPairFound:
        print(f"\n>> No combination of numbers add up to {kValue}\n\n")

    return numPairFound
```

```py
def evaluateSinglePass(numbers:list, kValue:int):
    numPairFound = False  # assuming false until proven true
    
    numbers.sort()
    for num in numbers:
        if kValue - num in numbers:
            numPairFound = True
            print(f"\n>> Found one! [{num} + {kValue - num} = {kValue}]\n\n")
            break
    
    if not numPairFound:
        print(f"\n>> No combination of numbers add up to {kValue}\n\n")

    return numPairFound
```